# How to create an empty array in kotlin?

Tags: arrays, kotlin

I'm using `Array(0, {i -> ""})` currently, and I would like to know if there's a better implementation such as `Array()`

plus, if I'm using `arrayOfNulls<String>(0) as Array<String>`, the compiler will alert me that this cast can never succeed. But it's the default implementation inside `Array(0, {i -> ""})`. Do I miss something?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33583235/how-can-i-tell-kotlin-that-an-array-or-collection-cannot-contain-nulls - one of the comments suggests that the warning is a bug

Answer (score 155, accepted):

As of late (June 2015) there is the Kotlin standard library function

```
public fun <T> arrayOf(vararg t: T): Array<T>
```

So to create an empty array of Strings you can write

```
val emptyStringArray = arrayOf<String>()
```

Comment: What about typed arrays like `IntArray`? Right now I am using `arrayOf<Int>().toIntArray()`, is there any better way?

Comment: what is the purpose of these methods? because we can't assign the size so we can't assign the value or get. array[0] throw `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:` exception.

Comment: @csharpfolk, you may use intArrayOf() to initialize an empty IntArray

Comment: This has an immutable length of `0`! So it's useful just for very special purposes that you don't want storing any ***data*** (just want ***type***). Use `Array(length){""}` to include a desired `length`. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29743160/how-to-create-a-empty-array-in-kotlin#answer-53901415) below for details.

Comment: @csharpfolk IntArray(size = 2)

Answer (score 50):

Just for reference, there is also `emptyArray`. For example,

```
var arr = emptyArray<String>()
```

See

- [doc](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/empty-array.html)
- [Array.kt](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/collections/Arrays.kt)

Comment: arr[0] throw `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:` how we can use it?

Comment: It's an empty array, you can't add/read anything to/from it. It may seem useless, but sometimes you have to pass an array somewhere and this allows you to construct an empty array easily.

Comment: this is better than Martian Odyssey's answer because when used in a data class to initialize an array, arrayOf causes a java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException while emptyArray() doesn't.

Comment: This has an immutable length of `0`! So it's useful just for very special purposes that you don't want storing any ***data*** (just want ***type***). Use `Array(length){""}` to include a desired `length`. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29743160/how-to-create-a-empty-array-in-kotlin#answer-53901415) below for details.

Answer (score 23):

## Empty or `null`? That's the question!

*To create an array of **`null`**s, simply use **`arrayOfNulls<Type>(length)`**.*

---

But to generate an **EMPTY** array of size `length`, use:

```kotlin
val arr = Array(length) { emptyObject }
```

Note that *you **must** define an `emptyObject`* properly per each data-type (beacause you don't want `null`s). E. g. for `String`s, `emptyObject` can be `""`. So:

```kotlin
val arr = Array(3) { "" }  // is equivalent for: arrayOf("","","")
```

---

[Here](https://pl.kotl.in/H1wFNohgE) is a *live example*. Note that the program runs with two sample arguments, by default.

Comment: arr.isEmpty() returns false though. i am guessing because we are fooling kotlin to treat "" as empty?

Answer (score 11):

null array

```
var arrayString=Array<String?>(5){null}
var nullArray= arrayOfNulls<String>(5)
```

Comment: This is an array of nulls, not empty strings as in question.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned above, you can use `IntArray(size)` or `FloatArray(size)`.

Answer (score 3):

I found two ways to create an empty array, the second way without a lambda:

```
var arr = Array (0, { i -> "" })
var arr2 = array<String>()
```

Regarding Kotlin's null strings, this is not allowed. You have to use *String?* type to allow strings to be null.

Answer (score 2):

**Use:**

```
@JvmField val EMPTY_STRING_ARRAY = arrayOfNulls<String>(0)
```

It returns an 0 size array of Strings, initialized with null values.

**1. Wrong:**

```
@JvmField val EMPTY_STRING_ARRAY = emptyArray<String>()
```

It returns `arrayOfNulls<String>(0)`

**2. Wrong:**

```
 @JvmField val EMPTY_STRING_ARRAY = arrayOf<String>()
```

It returns an array containing the Strings.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way to initialise array and assigning values :

```
val myArray: Array<String> = Array(2) { "" }
    myArray[0] = "Java"
    myArray[1] = "Kotlin"
```

Comment: myArray.isEmpty() returns false though. i am guessing because we are fooling kotlin to treat "" as empty?