# How can I tell Kotlin that an array or collection cannot contain nulls?

Tags: kotlin

If I create an array, then fill it, Kotlin believes that there may be nulls in the array, and forces me to account for this

```
val strings = arrayOfNulls<String>(10000)
strings.fill("hello")
val upper = strings.map { it!!.toUpperCase() } // requires it!!
val lower = upper.map { it.toLowerCase() } // doesn't require !!
```

Creating a filled array doesn't have this problem

```
val strings = Array(10000, {"string"})
val upper = strings.map { it.toUpperCase() } // doesn't require !!
```

How can I tell the compiler that the result of `strings.fill("hello")` is an array of NonNull?

Comment: I added an answer which addresses the question more directly.  Explains why it happens, and solutions that make sense given the context (you end up with lists, so why no embrace them earlier), and also the hack version to cast the array if you cannot resist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A rule of thumb: if in doubts, specify the types explicitly (there is a special refactoring for that):

```
val strings1: Array<String?> = arrayOfNulls<String>(10000)
val strings2: Array<String>  = Array(10000, {"string"})
```

So you see that `strings1` contains nullable items, while `strings2` does not. That and only that determines how to work with these arrays:

```
// You can simply use nullability in you code:
strings2[0] = strings1[0]?.toUpperCase ?: "KOTLIN"

//Or you can ALWAYS cast the type, if you are confident:
val casted = strings1 as Array<String>

//But to be sure I'd transform the items of the array:
val asserted = strings1.map{it!!}
val defaults = strings1.map{it ?: "DEFAULT"}
```

Comment: I thought that I'd tried `as Array<String>` and that it didn't compile, but I see that it does.

Comment: The problem I have is that `Array(10000, {"string})` is running code 10000 times rather than copying a value 1000 times - I can't believe it's as quick. Same for `map{it!!}`, although in both cases I suppose the compiler could be very smart.

Comment: When I say `as Array<String>` IntelliJ warns that the cast can never succeed. If I don't fill, it's right, and I get an exception. If I do fill, it's wrong, I don't get an exception, but that suggests that the cast has actually checked every element. So all your suggestions I think involve iterating over the array to check something that I know to be true.

Comment: Actually I retract that. IntelliJ warns that this cast can never succeed, but it actually always succeeds. https://gist.github.com/dmcg/c66db992c4b463a72042 So it isn't checking the contents of the array before making the cast

Comment: What you observed is a bug in the Kotlin plugin: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-6391 You can suppress the warning by using `@Suppress("CAST_NEVER_SUCCEEDS")`

Comment: @DuncanMcGregor: about the performance of Array(N, {"str"}) - there is no optimisation for lambdas by design. That allows you to put logging\debug printing anywhere and see what's going on.

Comment: Specifying the types to the left is not what makes the filled array be not nullable strings.  The type is inferred from the lambda AND if you specify a literal type on the function call or to the left of the `=` they would all have to match.  Changing the type to the left of `=` if it mismatched the lambda, would be an error.

Answer (score 2):

**Why the filled array works fine**

The filled array infers the type of the array during the call from the lambda used as the second argument:

```
val strings = Array(10000, {"string"})
```

produces `Array<String>`

```
val strings  = Array(10000, { it -> if (it % 2 == 0) "string" else null })
```

produces `Array<String?>`

Therefore changing the declaration to the left of the `=` that doesn't match the lambda does not do anything to help.  If there is a conflict, there is an error.

**How to make the arrayOfNulls work**

For the `arrayOfNulls` problem, they type you specify to the call `arrayOfNulls<String>` is used in the function signature as generic type `T` and the function `arrayOfNulls` returns `Array<T?>` which means nullable.  Nothing in your code changes that type.  The `fill` method only sets values into the existing array.

To convert this nullable-element array to non-nullable-element list, use:

```
val nullableStrings = arrayOfNulls<String>(10000).apply { fill("hello") }
val strings = nullableStrings.filterNotNull()
val upper = strings.map { it.toUpperCase() } // no !! needed
```

Which is fine because your `map` call converts to a list anyway, so why not convert beforehand.  Now depending on the size of the array this could be performant or not, the copy might be fast if in CPU cache.  If it is large and no performant, you can make this lazy:

```
val nullableStrings = arrayOfNulls<String>(10000).apply { fill("hello") }
val strings = nullableStrings.asSequence().filterNotNull()
val upper = strings.map { it.toUpperCase() } // no !! needed
```

Or you can stay with arrays by doing a copy, but really this makes no sense because you undo it with the `map`:

```
val nullableStrings = arrayOfNulls<String>(10000).apply { fill("hello") }
val strings: Array<String> = Array(nullableStrings.size, { idx -> nullableStrings[idx]!! })
```

Arrays really are not that common in Java or Kotlin code (JetBrains studied the statistics) unless the code is doing really low level optimization.  It could be better to use lists.

Given that you might end up with lists anyway, maybe start there too and give up the array.

```
val nullableStrings = listOf("a","b",null,"c",null,"d")
val strings =  nullableStrings.filterNotNull()
```

**But, if you can't stop the quest to use arrays, and really must cast one without a copy...**

You can always write a function that does two things:  First, check that all values are not null, and if so then return the array that is cast as not null. This is a bit hacky, but is safe only because the difference is nullability.

First, create an extension function on `Array<T?>`:

```
 fun <T: Any> Array<T?>.asNotNull(): Array<T> {
    if (this.any { it == null }) {
        throw IllegalStateException("Cannot cast an array that contains null")
    }
    @Suppress("CAST_NEVER_SUCCEEDS")
    return this as Array<T>
 }
```

Then use this function new function to do the conversion (element checked as not null cast):

```
val nullableStrings = arrayOfNulls<String>(10000).apply { fill("hello") }
val strings = nullableStrings.asNotNull() // magic!
val upperStrings = strings.map { it.toUpperCase() } // no error
```

But I feel dirty even talking about this last option.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to tell this to the compiler. The type of the variable is determined when it is declared. In this case, the variable is declared as an array that can contain nulls.

The fill() method does not declare a new variable, it only modifies the contents of an existing one, so it cannot cause the variable type to change.

Comment: So there is no way to cast Array<String?> to Array<String> ?

Comment: You always can cast nullability, but the responsibility is on you.